# File extension icon on Mac

Tags: macos

My application uses new proprietary file formats with extensions never been used before. I would like to associate specific icons to display my files in finder with nice iconography. As far as I know LaunchService is responsible to handle all these data, however I'm confused where, when and how shall I create associations.

Which entries I have to add to plist?

Where I need to actually register this extension - during installation? Is there any script for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [CFBundleDocumentTypes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685) key to your plist, see
[Storing Document Types Information in the Application's Property List](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000024)